# How to cancel routing go_router in redirection?

Tags: flutter, routes, state, flutter-go-router, gorouter

How to cancel routing?
If user is not premium user, Try to not allow to move to target routing.
For example, like below.

```
redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
  if (AuthState.of(context).isNotPremiumUser) {
   // cancel routing
  } else {
    return null;
  }   
},
```

How to do "return false" with go_router?

I did some research but nothing very conclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found is this.

```
redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
  if (AuthState.of(context).isNotPremiumUser) {
   context.goNamed(state.matchedLocation)
  } else {
    return null;
  }   
},
```

This cancels the navigation because the BuildContext of Redirect do not have permission to navigate. It also gives us a log which can be problematic or not.

> Assertion failed:
> inherited != null
> "No GoRouter found in context"

If you find this method problematic you also can navigate user to
NavigationErrorScreen

```
redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
  if (AuthState.of(context).isNotPremiumUser) {
    return '/navigation_error';
  } else {
    return null;
  }   
},
```

Navigation Error screen says You do not have permission or something and there must be a button for going back.

Navigating user same exact location can be tricky but i think it achievable with path_params or just calculate user  state and navigate home/sign_in screen with that button.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. The result is only coincidental because of the assertion. As the router isn't availble on the context object, it's not doing anything. I'm looking for a proper solution to this problem myself...

Answer (score 0):

In the `redirect` callback, the returned value will be the route that the router will redirect to. If the value is `null`, then it won't be redirected. To "cancel routing", you can return the current path (`state.matchedLocation`) as the redirecting target.

```dart
redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
  if (AuthState.of(context).isNotPremiumUser) {
    return state.matchedLocation;
  } else {
    return null;
  }   
}
```

Comment: state.matchedLocation is not the current route but the requested one, so it's the same as return null. At least in my tests.